# How to change user's UID&GID and what comes out of that

Tags: linux, mysql, user-management

I have MySQL data files on a thumb drive that are used on two hosts where `mysql` user's UIDs differ. As a result, MySQL fails to start when it's files have `0700` perms and an unknown UID as an owner.

I failed to find how to change MySQL's umask (and actually I don't like the idea of sharing these files to everyone), therefore I want to change UID of `mysql` user on both hosts so the files belong to the same user.

I'm going to change the UID and to `chown` all files owned by old mysql UID to the new user:

```
usermod --uid 900 --gid 900 mysql # assign the new uid
olduid=67   find / -user $olduid -group $olduid -print0 | xargs -0 chown "mysql:mysql"
```

Is this sufficient for an application to work in general case?
Maybe, I have better options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made some research and noticed two things one should take into account when changing UIDs&GIDs:

1. Numeric UID and GID do not always match: in my case `id -u mysql`=120 and `id -g mysql`=127
2. Not all files are owned by user 'mysql' and group 'mysql' simultaneously: these files should be searched for separately.

Therefore, we first change UID and GID:

```
user=mysql new_uid=600 old_uid=$(id -u $user)
group=mysql new_gid=600 old_gid=$(id -g $user)
sudo usermod -u $new_uid $user
sudo groupmod -g $new_gid $group
```

Then we `find` for files owned by the late user and group separately: 'user=mysql' goes to one file, 'group=mysql' goes to another file. Also we exclude some directories from `find` traversing tree:

```
chownlist=$(tempfile) chgrplist=$(tempfile) sudo find / \
\( \( -path "/proc" -or -path "/sys" -or -path "/dev" \) -prune \) -or \
\( \( -user $old_uid -fprint0 "$chownlist" \) , \
\( -group $old_gid -fprint0 "$chgrplist" \) \)
```

And only now it's okay to change owners and groups for these files found:

```
cat "$chownlist" | xargs -0 sudo chown $user
cat "$chgrplist" | xargs -0 sudo chown :$group
sudo rm "$chownlist" "$chgrplist"
```

Finally, we check if everything went okay: find files owned by unknown UIDs of GIDs:

```
sudo find / \( \( -path "/proc" -or -path "/sys" -or -path "/dev" \) -prune \) -or \( -nouser -or -nogroup -print \)
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's pretty much all you need to do. The only files which should need changing are the  logs and data files.

You might want to use find | xargs rather than a loop though.

Comment: I believe xargs is not acceptable here because there can be too many files for the shell to handle. Have you ever tried to `rm *` in a folder with thousands of files? :)

Comment: You were right, xargs can split dozens of files so the argument line is not overflowed. Thanks! :)